# add shinyBS popover on disabled button

Tags: r, shiny, shinybs

I haven't found any information in documentation of `shinyBS` and on the google/SO about how to use `trigger = 'manual'` on, for example, `addPopover` of `shinyBS`. I thought this would be the way to add a tooltip to a disabled button. (I dont want to do it with `div`'ving the button and giving `title` to `div`.
Also would be nice if someone has a way to add tooltips reactively to `shiny` apps

Comment: Can u please provide a reproducible example please. I am sure I can give u a hand

Comment: @PorkChop
There is an answer to the question with sufficiable example. Sry i couldn't answer earlier. The thing i'm trying to do is adding a popover over `disabled` button that shows up on `hover`ing it with mouse, and deleting it when the button becomes active.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since [shosaco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946974/add-shinybs-popover-on-disabled-button/44957474#44957474)'s solution didnt work for me, I got it to work this way:

```
if (input$disable) { 
  addCssClass("buttonId", "disabled")
  bsTooltip("buttonId", "This button is currently disabled.")
} else {
  bsTooltip("buttonId", "")
  removeCssClass("buttonId", "disabled")
}
observeEvent(input$buttonId, {
    if (!input$disable) {
      output$text <- renderText("Bla")
    } else {
      output$text <- renderText(NULL)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `trigger = manual` on the popover, then you need to define a script to toggle the popover, e.g. with jQuery:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS)


ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                       # press this button to trigger the popover
                       actionButton("addPopover", "Add Popover"),
                       
                       # a disabled button
                       disabled(actionButton("disabledButton", "This button is disabled")),
                       
                       # the popover to appear over the disabled button
                       bsPopover("disabledButton", "Popover", "Some text", trigger="manual"),
                       
                       # the script to trigger the popover
                       uiOutput("trigger")))


server <- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){
  
  # on checkbox selection, disable button and trigger the popover
  output$trigger <- renderUI({
    input$addPopover
    tags$script("$('#disabledButton').popover('toggle');")
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it, thanks. Unfortunately, I'm don't know anything in jQuery. Could you give me a hint about how do I do it so the `actionButton`, that's being currently disabled, shows a popover on a hover? In my app I tried to do something like this: 
`if(condition == TRUE) { shinyjs::disable(buttonId); addTooltip(session, id = 'buttonId', title = paste0('This button is currently disabled.')`, didnt work out quite well

Comment: updated my solution to the version including "no jquery"-solution... strange why `addPopover` doesn't work...

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, even with `bsTooltip`. It shows a tooltip if you move a mouse fast enough after un-ckecking the ckeckbox though. I didnt say I dont like jquery solution, it's just I need popover to be shown on `hover`, not on button click. But usual `hover` doesn't work with disabled buttons, that's why I thought about `manial` option.

Comment: It should work fine. The toolitp is only shown after *activating* the checkbox, i.e. disabling the button. It is *not* shown when button is enabled - that is what you wanted, right? What's your `packageVersion("shinyBS")`? I added a picture.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me on Chrome/IE/Opera. shinyBS version is `"shinyBS 0.61 2015-03-30"`

Comment: That approach that you've used in the second solution was the first thing i tried when I needed to add tooltip. It also didnt work with `addTooltip`, `addPopover`, `popify` and other things `shinyBS` provides to make this kinds of pop-ups.

Comment: Then there is a problem on your architecture I'm afraid, because it works fine on my side :-s

Comment: I tried it both on windows and mac, still not working. How do you run it? What are your machine / browser?

Comment: It did not work with downloadButton(...) for me.

Comment: Just re-testet, first one works for me, shinyBS 0.61, shinyjs 2.0.0

Comment: The second one seems to have changes in the last 4 years, so I removed that.